# Language Dropdown Based on Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple Select box with language Options. Each option will load a different page based on the selected language. The navigation works, but I need the default selected item to be based on the page's ID, which is set using PHP.

I have jQuery 1.12 already loading on the page, so that library can be used if needed.

```
<?php
    $body_id = "en";
?>

<form id="language" method="post">
    <select class="language" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
        <option selected="selected">LANGUAGE</option>
        <option value="index-da.php">DANSK</option>
        <option value="index-de.php">DEUTSCH</option>
        <option value="index.php">ENGLISH</option>
        <option value="index-es.php">ESPA&#209;OL</option>
        <option value="index-fr.php">FRAN&#199;AIS</option>
        <option value="index-it.php">ITALIANO</option>
        <option value="index-pl.php">POLSKI</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: `$body_id` does not match anything from `options`

Comment: Yes, I have not written that, because I don't know what needs to be written. I assume something in jQuery calling the $body_id and adding the selected attribute to an Option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `filter` to get target `option` element and apply condition based on the value of the `option`

```js
var $body_id = "en";
var filtered = $('.language').find('option').filter(function() {
  return this.value.split('.')[0].split('-')[1] == $body_id;
});
if (filtered.length) {
  filtered.prop('selected', true);
} else {
  $('.language').find('option[value="index.php"]').prop('selected', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="language" method="post">
  <select class="language" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option selected="selected">LANGUAGE</option>
    <option value="index-da.php">DANSK</option>
    <option value="index-de.php">DEUTSCH</option>
    <option value="index.php">ENGLISH</option>
    <option value="index-es.php">ESPA&#209;OL</option>
    <option value="index-fr.php">FRAN&#199;AIS</option>
    <option value="index-it.php">ITALIANO</option>
    <option value="index-pl.php">POLSKI</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**For other language**

```js
var $body_id = "da";
var filtered = $('.language').find('option').filter(function() {
  return this.value.split('.')[0].split('-')[1] == $body_id;
});
if (filtered.length) {
  filtered.prop('selected', true);
} else {
  $('.language').find('option[value="index.php"]').prop('selected', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="language" method="post">
  <select class="language" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option selected="selected">LANGUAGE</option>
    <option value="index-da.php">DANSK</option>
    <option value="index-de.php">DEUTSCH</option>
    <option value="index.php">ENGLISH</option>
    <option value="index-es.php">ESPA&#209;OL</option>
    <option value="index-fr.php">FRAN&#199;AIS</option>
    <option value="index-it.php">ITALIANO</option>
    <option value="index-pl.php">POLSKI</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Rayon! Unfortunately this always sets English as the selected language. If the user visits the Italian page, it needs Italian to be the selected Option. Each page has a $body_id set. En for English. De for German. It for Italian. etc.

Comment: Ah, I see! That first var needs to go on every page! Works perfectly, thank sir.

Comment: @ChrisCather, I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Comment: Bonus round, can I have a line that calls the PHP variable instead of declaring it again on every page?

Comment: @ChrisCather, `var $body_id='<?php echo $body_id; ?>'` will solve the purpose!

Answer (score 1):

instead of repeating yourself all over the place, you could just make an array of your languages and echo your template around that iteration, then check the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to see if it's equal and set it selected if so.

```
<?php
$languages = array(
  'da' => 'DANSK',
  'de' => 'DEUTSCH',
  'en' => 'ENGLISH',
  'es' => 'ESPA&#209;OL',
  'fr' => 'FRAN&#199;AIS',
  'it' => 'ITALIANO',
  'pl' => 'POLSKI'
);
?>

<form id="language" method="post">
    <select class="language" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>LANGUAGE</option>

<?php
foreach ($languages as $code => $language){

  $page = "index-$code.php";

  if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === $page)
    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
  else
    $selected = '';

  echo "<option value='$page' $selected>$language</option>".PHP_EOL;

}
?>

    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like this would be more flexible:

```
<?php
$body_id = !empty($_POST['lang']) ? $_POST['lang'] : '';

$options = array
(
    'da' => 'Dansk',
    'de' => 'Deutsch',
    'en' => 'English',
    'es' => 'Español',
    'fr' => 'Français',
    'it' => 'Italiano',
    'pl' => 'Polski'
);
?>
<form action="<?=getenv('PHP_SELF')?>" method="post">
    <select name="lang" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option>Language</option>
<?php foreach ($options as $key => $val):?>
        <option value="<?=$key?>"<?=($key == $body_id ? 'selected' : '')?>><?=htmlentities($val)?></option>
<?php endforeach?>
    </select>
</form>
```